# How to save data serially in Active Android(ORM) in android?

Tags: android

I am working on Active Android(ORM) which is a library to save the values in the sqlite database. The values are saving serially until index no 9, the moment I am saving the 10 item in the table, it comes at second position although it should be on 10 position in the table which is list in my case as I am using Active Android. What I want is data should be saved serially from 1 to 100.

What I am understanding is, it is working like the digits starting with 1 are grouped together but I don't want this.

My Model class is like :

```
/**
 * Created by touchstone on 23-09-2016.
 */

@Table(name = "QuestionsNAnswers")


public class QuestionsNAnswers extends Model {

    @Column(name = "questionNo",index = true,unique = true,notNull =true,onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
    public String questionNo;
    @Column(name = "optionSelected")
    public String optionSelected;
}
```

And My Sample code to save the data is :

```
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //SAVE THE SELECTED VALUE IN THE SQLITE DATABASE(ACTIVE ANDROID IN OUR CASE)
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            QuestionsNAnswers questionsNAnswers = new QuestionsNAnswers();
            questionsNAnswers.questionNo = questionNo;
            questionsNAnswers.optionSelected = optionNo;
            //save the records in the database
            questionsNAnswers.save()o
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess the default data type of the "questionNo" column is TEXT (not numeric). So it is sorted alphabetically where "10" comes before "2".